# How do I format date and month separate on the ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services

I trying to create a format that have the Day of and the Month ex: Dated this ***25th*** day of ***February*** 2021

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality to do this in SSRS.

I created some custom code to format dates with an ordinal. I think I created the function using some logic I saw in an SQL statement.

The function code would go in the reports's properties' CODE tab:

```
Function - Ordinal Numbers

Public Function FormatOrdinal(ByVal day As Integer) as String 

DIM Ordinal as String = ""

    IF day Mod 100 = 11 or day Mod 100 = 12 or day Mod 100 = 13     ' If 11, 12 or 13, add a "th" NOT a "st", "nd" or "rd" 

        Ordinal = "th" 
    
    ELSE    ' Start a new select case for the rest of the numbers 
    
        SELECT Case day Mod 10 
            Case 1 ' 1 or 21 = “st"
                Ordinal = "st" 
            Case 2 ' 2 or 22 = "nd" 
                Ordinal = "nd" 
            Case 3 ' 3 or 33 = "rd" 
                Ordinal = "rd" 
            Case Else ' Otherwise "Th" 
                Ordinal = "th"

        END SELECT 

    END IF 

    Return day.ToString() + Ordinal 

END FUNCTION
```

The expression for the text box would be:

```
="Dated this " & CODE.FormatOrdinal(Day(Fields!THE_DATE.Value)) & " day of " & FORMAT(Fields!THE_DATE.Value, "MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: This it nice but I should have been more clearer, all I want is just the format for Day and month Ex: Done this ___________day of _____________________________ 2021 I want to fill in the blank just those two I know there have to be a built-in function just for day and month

Comment: @DThomas221 - Then you could use the parts of the expression. The day would be `CODE.FormatOrdinal(Day(Fields!THE_DATE.Value))` and the month `FORMAT(Fields!THE_DATE.Value, "MMMM")` - M format is for month with MMM shows the abbreviated month and MMMM is the full month name.

Comment: Do I need to create a SQL statement just for that expression??

Comment: @DThomas221 - You would just need to change the `Fields!THE_DATE.Value` to whatever you want to use for the date, a field a parameter...

Comment: @DThomas221. There is no need to do anything in SQL. Hannover's answer is a custom function that you need to add to your report ( go to report properties then code then paste the function in there), then you can just use `CODE.FormatOrdinal(Day(Fields!THE_DATE.Value))` to get the day part and `FORMAT(Fields!THE_DATE.Value, "MMMM")` to get the month name.